# Is there a way to get plotly graphics to render when an html file generated with flexdashboard is opened locally?

Tags: r, knitr, r-plotly, flexdashboard

I have been producing html files with flexdashboard and plotly graphics for a while now, and only recently noticed that tabs within my dashboard aren't rendering plotly graphics when I open the file from a local drive.

Consider this basic .rmd file:

````
---
title: "Test Dashboard"

output:
  html_document: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
  pdf_document: default

---
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(arules)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(reshape2)
library(stringr)
library(crosstalk)

rf<-data.frame(happiness=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
           laziness=c(3,4,6,1,2,5,6,1))






```


Association Rules
==================================
Column {.tabset}
----------------------------------

### Table


```{r what2, echo=FALSE, collapse=TRUE, message=FALSE,warning=FALSE}
datatable(rf, filter = 'top', extensions = 'Buttons', options = list(dom = 'Bfrtip', buttons = 
c('csv', 'excel','copy', I('colvis')),pageLength = 20, autoWidth = TRUE),rownames = FALSE)
```




### Plot

```{r what, echo=FALSE, collapse=TRUE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}


P<-plot_ly(rf,
       x=~happiness,
       y=~laziness, 
        color = ~happiness)
P
```
````

In the above code, I included packages I frequently load should someone be aware of the fact that one of these packages is the culprit.

When I knit this .rmd in Rstudio to produce an .html file on my hard drive, the file saves as expected.

Navigating to the file and opening it (Chrome and firefox have been tested) results in a user seeing the table just fine, but the tab for the plot is blank.

My current workaround to actually see the plot is to append "#plot" to the end of the filepath in my browser and hitting refresh.  When I do so, the plot appears and all is well.

While this works for me, it does make using my output files less fun for others.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like plotly is unable to get default width and height, and thus uses NULL. Manually setting these in the plot_ly call makes the plot appear, e.g.:

```
P<-plot_ly(rf,
       x=~happiness,
       y=~laziness, 
        color = ~happiness,
       width = 600, 
       height = 400)
```

Answer (score 0):

The function renderPlotly() in flexdashboard dynamically resizes ploty graphs. I used in in one of my blog posts on Flexdahboard, see: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/shiny-dashboards-with-flexdashboard-e66aaafac1f2